# Twilio studio variable

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I have been trying to compute and set a flow variable using liquid template syntax. What I need to do is filter an array to remove a value from it and set that into a variable.

First I tried using `where` expression but it's not documented in Tiwlio docs, so my guess is it's not supported.

I assign `body` & `options` but in Studio Flow these would already defined values

Example code:

```
{% assign body = "Test2" %}
{% assign options = "Test,Test2,Test3" | split: ","  %}
{% assign options_filtered = "" | split: "" %}
{{options_filtered | where: body }}
```

Since the above attempt was unuseful, I tried populating the array manually and then joining it into a string

Example code:

```
{% assign body = "Test2" %}
{% assign options = "Test,Test2,Test3" | split: ","  %}
{% assign options_filtered = "" | split: "" %}
{% for item in options %}
 {% if item != body %}
  {% assign options_filtered = options_filtered | concat: item %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{options_filtered | join: ","}}
```

This approach was unsuccessful as well, I just get errors that returned value is not a JSON.

What I ended up doing is creating a Twilio Function where I pass a stringified array and value to filter out, but I would still like to avoid using the function if possible.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found this worked:

```
{% assign body = "Test2" %}
{% assign options = "Test,Test2,Test3" | split: "," %}
{% assign options_filtered = options | remove: body | join: "," %}
{{ options_filtered }}
```

Make sure you are only using options documented in [Twilio's Liquid guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/liquid-template-language). For example, `concat` and `where` are not present. `remove` is the filter you need to filter a list.

Answer (score 0):

@philnash

Well, this sort of works if the items in array all all different, but I have a problem if `body` is s substring in an option, like for example:

```
{% assign body = "About" %}
{% assign options = "About App,About Company,About Company Services" | split: "," %}
{% assign options_filtered = options | remove_first: body | join: "," %}
{{ options_filtered }}
```

Output would be

```
App,About Company,About Company Services
```